# Como posso inverter uma lista encadeada simples sem utilizar um ponteiro anterior

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Tenho que resolver um problema de ficção de estrutura de dados que consiste em inverter um lista encadeada porém como posso inverter um lista se não possuo os elemento dela (Menos é claro o p-inicio e o p->fim )segue o código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct TipoElemento {
    int valor;
    struct TipoElemento *proximo;
}TElemento;


typedef struct TipoLista {
    TElemento *inicio;
    TElemento *fim;
}TLista;

void inicializar (TLista *p){
    p->inicio = NULL;
    p->fim = NULL;
}

void inserir (TLista *p){
    TElemento *novo;
    novo = new TElemento;
    printf("Entre com um novo elemento ");
    scanf("%d",&novo->valor);
    novo->proximo = NULL;

    if (p->inicio == NULL){
        p->inicio = novo;
        p->fim = novo;
    }else{
        p->fim->proximo = novo;
        p->fim = novo;

    }

}

void apresentar (TLista *p){
    TElemento *aux = p->inicio;          // ao criar a variavel aux devemos inicializar com o primeiro elemento da LISTA // P->INICIO

    if(p->inicio == NULL){
        printf("Lista vazia ");
    }else{
        while(aux != NULL){  // eu quero APRESENTAR MINHA LISTA ----AUX
            printf("%d",aux->valor);
            aux = aux->proximo;
        }
    }
}

void inverter (TLista *p){
    TLista *aux = p->fim;

    where (){
        aux = 
    }

}

int main (){
    TLista aep;
    TLista aep2;
    int opcao;

    inicializar(&aep);
    inicializar (&aep2);
    do 
    {
        printf("\n ****** ESTRUTURAS DE DADOS - PILHA ESTATICA ******\n");
        printf("\nOpcoes: \n\n");
        printf(" 1 - Inserir novo elemento \n");
    //  printf(" 2 - Consultar elemento \n");
    //  printf(" 3 - Remover elemento \n");
        printf(" 4 - Apresentar todos os elementos \n");
    //  printf(" 0 - para sair \n\n");
    //  printf("Entre com a sua opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao); /* Le a opcao do usuario */
        switch (opcao)
        {
            case 1: inserir(&aep); break;
            //case 2: consultar(&E); break;
        //  case 3: retirarPilha(&P); break;
            case 4: apresentar(&aep); break;
            case 0: break;
            default: printf("\n\n Opcao invalida"); getch(); break;
        }
    } while (opcao != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira função inverte os elementos da lista e a segunda função inverte a referência de inicio e fim.

```
void inverteElementos (TElemento *e, TElemento *ant){
    if(e->proximo!=NULL)
        inverteElementos(e->proximo, e);
    e->proximo = ant;
}

void inverter (TLista *p){
    inverteElementos(p->inicio, NULL);

    //Inverte inicio com fim
    TElemento *aux = p->inicio;
    p->inicio = p->fim;
    p->fim = aux;
}
```

Comment: O ponteiro E significa o que ?
e por que você chamou a inverteElementos dentro dela mesmo novamente ?

Comment: O ponteiro E é apenas um elemento da lista que será passado para a função(começando pelo primeiro elemento). A inverteElementos chamando ela mesma, chama-se recursão, procure a respeito caso não tenha trabalhado ainda com funções recursivas. Basicamente o que a função inverteElementos faz nesse caso é percorrer toda a lista passando sempre o endereço do anterior, depois ela volta a lista fazendo com que cada elemento aponte para seu elemento anterior.

Comment: O que seria o ant? Você fez lista encadeada dupla?

Answer (score -1):

```
void inverter_lista(struct no **lista)
{
  struct no* nova_lista = NULL;
  struct no* tmp;
  int i;

  
    while (*lista != NULL)
    {
        tmp = *lista;
        *lista = (*lista)->proximo;
      tmp->proximo = nova_lista;
      nova_lista = tmp;
    }
  *lista = nova_lista;

}
```